# C++ 3D Vector Updating malloc incorrect checksum

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, malloc

I'm just learning C++ coming from Python. I'm very new to the memory management concepts and I'm having a really hard time understanding what is going wrong with my approach. My goal is to take a list of numbers from user input and place them in an NxN vector graph. Each node is a vector storing `{input_number, row_index, col_index, 0}`. Can someone explain what specifically is going wrong here? The for loop seems to get to the second row and then bugs out.

Source Code:

```
int N;
cin >> N;
int total = N * N;
vector<vector<vector<int>>> graph (N, vector<vector<int>>(N, vector<int>(4)));
int col = 0; int row = 0; int startcol; int startrow;
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) { 
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    graph[row][col] = vector<int>({num, row, col, 0});
    if (num == 1) {
        startrow = row;
        startcol = col;
    }
    if (col < N) {
        col++;
    }
    else {
        col = 0;
        row++;
    }
}
int result = search(graph, startrow, startcol, N);
```

Error:

```
a.out(7393,0x7fffc20433c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x100300138: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
```

I eventually used a different approach by nesting to for loops and updating each element of the node, one at a time. I have a feeling this issue has something to do with overwriting the entire node vector in the line `graph[row][col] = vector<int>({num, row, col, 0})` but that would work perfectly fine in Python (probably because it's handling all the memory management in the bg), so I don't understand here why I can't just replace an N vector of 0's with an N vector of new ints.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, can you provide a full example which fail each time. here what I tried : http://cpp.sh/9bzja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current logic `col < N` check is done after accessing `graph[row][col]`.  This means `col` becomes equal to `N`, tries to access `graph[0][N]` and only after that resets `col`.

So you have to check `col` before accessing `graph` or check 'if (col < N-1)' afterwards.

Comment: Oh wow, I feel stupid. This is so obvious I can't believe I didn't catch it. I was so busy thinking it was something super complicated. Also I'm so used to much less cryptic messages like "IndexError: list assignment index out of range", which would have been obvious immediately haha. Thank you!